# ormlite: sql statement not like throws exception

Tags: android, ormlite

I use ormlite. I want to execute the sql statement "not like".

I used not().like() but I got exception "can't add: NOT without comparison".

What did I do wrong? I have looked for examples using "not like" with ormlite but 
I haven't found anything online.

Comment: what version of ormlite are you using?

Comment: Can you please show the exception with all of the caused stanzas?  Posting a question about an exception without showing it is a no-no.

Comment: Remember to accept my answer mike if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> I used not().like() but I got exception "can't add: NOT without comparison".

This turned out to be a bug in ORMLite that was fixed in version 4.48.  It specifically was not handling queries that did something similar to:

```
where.eq(...).and().not().like(...);
```

If there is any problem with the in-line mechanisms for building queries, you can always switch to the operations that take arguments which is more straightforward.  See the docs on the [various ways to build queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries).

Comment: Thank you Gray. I will try v4.48 and accept you answer if it is ok. Thanks for the library!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at source code from [trunk](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/code/HEAD/tree/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.java#l626), I assume that you get exception because of some previous clause (probably and() or or()). Make sure that all methods requiring future clause are followed up by proper clause. and().not() will not work...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's true that I use and().not(). So how should I state my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.queryBuilder().where().rawComparison("column", "NOT LIKE", "value")
```